# Exceeding 8060 bytes when writing an object to a table - Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I have this communication when I'm trying add new object to my local database:

> The table definition or the row size exceeds the maximum row size of 8060 bytes.

My table has the following structure:

```
[Table]
public class SomeClass
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string String2 { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string String3 { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string String4 { get; set; }
}
```

3 of these strings (String2, String3, String4) will contain the 2000-3000 characters.
When I am trying to write smaller data (between 1000 to 1500 characters) everything works.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server stores the records in pages, pages are 8k, and therefore a records cannot exceed that size (difference to 8k is administrative date).

You need to change your text column definitions to `text`, `ntext`, or `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` to store longer texts. These blob columns are not restricted by page size.

Comment: Thanks for Your response.

I used [Column(DbType = "NText")] and it is working now! But varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) are not supported by compact edition db.